# .htaccess crashes in some cases and gives 404 page not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess configuration :

`RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php?|css|js|images|robots\.txt)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]`

the problem is the htaccess crashes in some cases and give 404 error (page not found)
here is some hints :

1. all pages contain Arabic characters
2. some times the difference between two urls is very small (one normal character)
3. if i add /index.php after the domain name it works for all but i don't want to let index.php inside the url
4. i am working in local machine on Xampp but the same code with same HTACCESS file works correctly on Linux server

I will write some cases that htaccess crashes and not (the difference between the tow links at first of each list is just one normal Arabic character )
it doesn't work for these :

1- http://localhost/mywebsite/article/13057/%D9%85%D9%86    (the parameter is "من")

2- http://localhost/mywebsite/article/13057/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A6%D9%84%D8%A9-%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B6%D9%88%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85

3- http://localhost/mywebsite/article/12803/%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A2%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AA-14-19-%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B0%D8%A7-%D8%AD%D9%82%D8%AF-%D8%A5%D8%A8%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%B3-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%89-%D8%A2%D8%AF%D9%85-

and work correctly for these:

1- http://localhost/mywebsite/article/13057/%D9%81%D9%86  (the parameter is "فن")

2- http://localhost/mywebsite/article/514/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%B3-61-95%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A2%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AA180-184-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9

3- http://localhost/mywebsite/article/2562/%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%A1-004-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%B31569-%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A2%D9%8A%D8%A9-31-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%B1-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%BA%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%B1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your rewrite code, it doesn't allow for non Latin letter as far as i can see.
Try something like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?art_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

I'm answering from mobile so sorry about the display